# No results with MINUS and OPTIONAL on same pattern, even when OPTIONAL doesn't match

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This is my data

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/rs#>
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

:user1  :hasFirstName    "user1First".
:user1  :hasLastName    "user2Last".
:user1  :hasMobileNumber    "013434334".

:user2  :hasFirstName   "ania".
:user2  :hasLastName    "ania".
```

This is my query (to get all people without a phone number)

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example.org/rs#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?firstName ?lastName ?mobileNumber
{
  ?user :hasFirstName ?firstName.
  ?user :hasLastName    ?lastName.

  minus {?user :hasMobileNumber ?mobileNumber}
}
```

it works very good. However, it i added an optional like this:

```sql
PREFIX : <http://example.org/rs#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?firstName ?lastName ?mobileNumber
{
  ?user :hasFirstName ?firstName.
  ?user :hasLastName    ?lastName.
  optional {?user :hasMobileNumber ?mobileNumber}
  minus {?user :hasMobileNumber ?mobileNumber}
}
```

the reuslt becomes empty though it was just optional, and the optional will not afect the result of the query since both users will be results (with and without optional)

so why this is happening plase ?

Comment: This is minimual data bty :) you can replicate the problem directly

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation, there's a description of what **minus** does, and even an example.

> #### [8.2 Removing Possible Solutions](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-minus)
>
> The other style of negation provided in SPARQL is MINUS which
>   evaluates both its arguments, then calculates solutions in the
>   left-hand side that are not compatible with the solutions on the
>   right-hand side.

In your case, the left hand side, once you add the **optional**, you *always* have a binding for **?user**, and sometimes have a binding for **?mobileNumber**.   The results with the **optional**, but without the **minus**, look like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| user   | firstName    | lastName    | mobileNumber |
======================================================
| :user1 | "user1First" | "user2Last" | "013434334"  |
| :user2 | "ania"       | "ania"      |              |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, when the **minus** and **optional** are both present, you get no results.  I assume you understand why **user1** is excluded.  But why is **user2** excluded?

The "left hand" part includes the bindings

```
------------------------------------------------------
| user   | firstName    | lastName    | mobileNumber |
======================================================
| :user2 | "ania"       | "ania"      |              |
------------------------------------------------------
```

and the right hand part (the part in the **minus**) doesn't have any matches.  That means that *all* the solutions in the left hand part *are* compatible with it.  That means that when you get the

> solutions in the left-hand side that are not compatible with the
>   solutions on the right-hand side.

you get *nothing*, because all the solutions in the left-hand side are not "not compatible" with the solutions on the right-hand side.

Comment: *right hand part (the part in the minus) doesn't have any matches. That means that all the solutions in the left hand part are compatible with it.* . That I didn't get, maybe you could tell me please what does "compatible" mean in this syntax, and why in the case where no optional there, i still get result?

Comment: @aniadavid the pattern in your minus and in your optional always get exactly the same values (either they both have values or the both don't),so they're *always* compatible.  MINUS removes all the compatible results.  Since all the results are compatible, all the results get removed.

Comment: @aniadavid when there is no OPTIONAL then sometimes the MINUS pattern is incompatible with the rest of the query and the incompatibleresults are the ones that you receive.

Comment: I am sorry, I understood your answer, but i just understood in the case where there is an optional, honestly I can't see the difference when there is no optional, i tried to do like you, (draw table of bindings ..) and I ended up with the same senario as yours, but you're telling me they are different. You treated every row in the table separately, and without or with optional, you will get the same rows